# How to install the documentation for a package

Tags: documentation

I installed the hanging package with tkmgr gui but it came without documentation. How can install the documentation?

Comment: Welcome! It is part of the `hanging` package supplied by TeX Live.

Comment: What do you get when you type `texdoc hanging` from your terminal?

Comment: `tlmgr` will install the 'entire' code + documentation bundled unless you've turned off documentation installation. We'll need some more context to gibe more assistance.